# Where do i define the juncion table in many-to-many relationship in Laravel's Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, eloquent

Here in the eloquent i see the Many to Many relationship:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

I am not using Migrations and made two tables 'users' and a table 'roles' in phpmyadmin. 
They both have a 'id' and 'name' column. Now i made the following models:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
    }

}



class Role extends Eloquent {

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

}
```

My first question is. Do is still need to make junction table in phpmyadmin? 
And if yes how do i tell Eloquent that (for example 'users_roles') is my junction table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must indeed have the table, and you can either follow Laravel conventions or specify it manually in the call to `$this->belongsTomany();`. Both ways are documented in the [Eloquent documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many). The convention is in alphabetical order and singular table names (roles, users, role_user). To specify it in the call you can specify all sorts of things: `return $this->belongsToMany('ForeignModel', 'pivot_table', 'local_id', 'foreign_id');`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you still need to create the table.

In your models, add the table name as a second argument to belongsToMany.